# IEnumerable transform extension function using delegate?

Tags: .net, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

I just found out I'm not as fluent with `delegate` and `action` and the other one as I would want...

I have a certain `IEnumerable<T>` which I would like to transform to a `IEnumerable<object>` using a delegate function that creates `object` as an anonymous object. **An extension method would come in handy here or might already exist?**

This (or something like this) should be possible right?

```
IEnumerable<SomeBllObject> list;
IEnumerable<object> newList = list.Transform(x => return new {
                        someprop = x.SomeProp, 
                        otherprop = x.OtherProp
                  });
```

Comment: Can you not use Select - `list.Select(x => return new {} )`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you've just described the `Select` method:

```
IEnumerable<object> newList = list.Select(x => new {
                        someprop = x.SomeProp, 
                        otherprop = x.OtherProp
                  });
```

For .NET 3.5 you'd need to cast the result of your delegate, as it doesn't have generic covariance:

```
IEnumerable<object> newList = list.Select(x => (object) new {
                        someprop = x.SomeProp, 
                        otherprop = x.OtherProp
                  });
```

Or use implicitly typed local variables and get a strongly typed sequence:

```
var newList = list.Select(x => new {
                        someprop = x.SomeProp, 
                        otherprop = x.OtherProp
                  });
```

Comment: Great, the select method is indeed exactly what I need!

Comment: Would you mind waiting 5 minutes before answering my question next time? Some programmer built-in a 5 minute 'accept-answer-delay'.... ;)